# Navigate through page ids except certain ids - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I have a store where you can navigate to the next/previous product by clicking buttons.

I used this tutorial: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/get-previousnext-record-ids

My problem is there are 4 ids of certain products I want to skip. I don't want to display these at all.

How can I do this?

Here's my attempt:

```
@unless($product->id == 17 || $product->id == 18 || $product->id == 20 || $product->id == 22  )

    <?php  
        $previous = Product::where('id', '<', $product->id)->max('id');

        $next = Product::where('id', '>', $product->id)->min('id');
    ?> 

    <a href="{{URL::to('products/'.$previous)}}" id="prevProd"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
    <a href="{{URL::to('products/'.$next)}}" id="nextProd"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
@endunless
```

Should I be doing this in my route instead? This doesn't work. It still displays the products with those ids, it just doesn't have the next/previous buttons.

My route:

```
Route::get('products/{id}', function($id)
{
    $oProduct = Product::find($id);

    return View::make('singleproduct')->with('product', $oProduct)->with("cart",Session::get("cart"));

})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple suggestions:

You want to try and keep complicated logic out of your view. It's not your view's responsibility to determine the previous/next ids. Those values should be passed in.

Also, you may want to consider moving the logic in the route into a Controller. All the route should be doing is pointing to the controller/method that should be run. It is not the route's job to actually handle any logic (outside of where to send the application).

Finally, as far as your functionality goes, you may want to consider extracting the logic out to a method on your Product model. Though, I wouldn't make it a model scope method, since you're returning a value and not a query object. Something along the lines of:

```
public function getNextId(array $except = null) {
    $query = $this->where('id', '>', $this->id);
    if (!empty($except)) {
        $query->whereNotIn('id', $except);
    }
    return $query->min('id');
}

public function getPreviousId(array $except = null) {
    $query = $this->where('id', '<', $this->id);
    if (!empty($except)) {
        $query->whereNotIn('id', $except);
    }
    return $query->max('id');
}
```

Now, in your route (or controller if you move to that), you can do:

```
function($id) {
    $excludeIds = array(17, 18, 20, 22);
    // you may want some logic to handle when $id is one of the excluded
    // ids, since a user can easily change the id in the url
    $oProduct = Product::find($id);
    return View::make('singleproduct')
        ->with('product', $oProduct)
        ->with('cart', Session::get('cart'))
        ->with('previous', $oProduct->getPreviousId($excludeIds))
        ->with('next', $oProduct->getNextId($excludeIds));
}
```

Comment: Legend! Thanks for this. And for the advice. I'm new and haven't put much logic in my models. Good to see how it's done. This works great! Just in case anyone else wants to use this, there's a typo in the model functions. whereNotIn not whereNotId. Thanks again!

Comment: @thomasjaunism Sorry about that.  Fixed the code typo.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Glad I could help.